# Listing physical quantities

Tags: lists

As a non-native speaker, I had some trouble phrasing my question for Google, so I finally decided to ask here:

What is the correct way to write an enumeration/list of several values with the same physical unit e.g., "50, 100 Hz" or "50 Hz, 100 Hz"?

Does the same rule also apply for more items e.g., "50, 100 and 150"?

Note: this is a list, not a range.

Comment: Can you give us an example with a full sentence? In any case I can think of where there's two values like that, we'd join them with "and" rather than a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly common to list values and then state the unit once, at the end (eg *this medicine comes in packs of 25, 50 and 100 tablets*).

It is also common to state the unit once at the end of a range indicated with a hyphen (eg *this radio station broadcasts on 87-91 FM*).

But there is no right or wrong here, and many style choices are simply taken for the purpose of making matters clear. If you think that the way you have written something will cause confusion, then maybe it is better to clarify each value with the measure.

I found this example about medicines:

> This medicine contains less than 1 mmol sodium (23 mg) per 25 mg, 50 mg and 100 mg tablet

I can only guess at why each value has been written with the measure, but I think it was likely done to avoid confusion. You wouldn't want anyone to confuse the number of milligrams in their dose with the number of tablets in a pack, for example.

Also, options are sometimes separated with a forward slash rather than a comma (eg *25/50/100*), but could two number options be mistaken for a fraction? A statement like "*these tablets come in 25/50mg*" could be confusing - might a person think that each tablet contains 25mg out of their 50mg dose and accidentally take double their dose? Safer to write "*25mg/50mg*".

There doesn't seem to be any possible confusion around your example. There are no other measures involved to confuse it with, and I would say that the choice is entirely yours.